# Finding the general term of a sequence (if there's any)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, problem-solving, pattern-recognition

I would like to know if it's possible to find an expression for the following sequence $\;\{a_n\},\;n=0,\,1,\,2,\,3,\,\dots\;$

$1, 3 , 7, 13, 21...$

Someone would like to explain me what I have to do to solve it? I can see a pattern on them, it adds two more than the previous term added (2,4,6,8...) (like 2^n).

So I would like to know the general term($a_n\,=...$) solution, but mainly I would like to the explanation.

Edit: Solution: $a_n\,=n^2-n+1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Compare $a_n$ with $n^2$ for the first few values of $n$.

**Added:**

$$\begin{array}{rcc}
n:&1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\
n^k:&1&4&9&16&25&36&49\\
a_n:&1&3&7&13&21&31&43
\end{array}$$

What’s the difference between the last two rows of that table?

Comment: That helps where? Sorry for the missunderstanding. My first few u mean 1 and 3?

Comment: @Exprove: I mean for $n=1,2,3,4$, and $5$, say. Make a table with three rows: the top row shows $n$, the second row shows $n^2$, and the bottom row shows $a_n$. You should see a pattern that lets you write down an equation for $a_n$ in terms of $n$. (I’m assuming that $a_1=0$ and $a_2=3$.)

Comment: I guess that didn't help. I cant solve it :(

Comment: @Exprove: You’re not experimenting enough. Take a look at the further hint that I just added?

Comment: Ok xD so easy I guess... I am sorry. I din't understand what u meant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Exprove: You’re welcome.

Comment: Solution: $a_n\,=n^2-n+1$

Comment: @Exprove: Looks good to me.

Comment: This isn't an arithmetic or a geometric sequence right? In the first place I was like trying to check the ratio (which gave me something like 2^(n-1)) but then I saw this was wrong.

Comment: @Exprove: No, it’s neither arithmetic nor geometric. An arithmetic sequence grows linearly, and a geometric sequence grows exponentially; this one grows quadratically.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be solved as a recurrence relation.

$$\Delta a_n=a_n-a_{n-1}=2(n-1)$$
Sum from $n=2$ to $n=m$:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=2}^m a_n-a_{n-1}&=2\sum_{n=2}^m (n-1)\\
a_m-\underbrace{a_1}_{1}&=2\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}n=m(m-1)\\
a_m&=m^2-m+1\\
\text{or}\qquad a_n&=n^2-n+1
\end{align}$$